# Unable to find hours between two dates MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table in my database and I have two date columns (varchar) in my table date1 and date2. I want to find difference in hours between date1 and date2. Database is created using mariadb.

I already tried:

```
timediff('date1','date2')
```

But getting null.

Comment: Write your SQL query please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe issue is you are passing column name as String so it is unable to parse it. Remove quotes from the column and it will run as a charm.

```
SELECT timediff(date1, date2) from TABLE
```

EDIT:- 
Use STR_TO_DATE() method to convert string to date type...
So your final Query Will be

```
SELECT timediff(STR_TO_DATE(date1, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s'),STR_TO_DATE(date2, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s')) from TABLE
```

Comment: I just executed in my system ...it is working fine...Can you please tell datatype of your date1 and date2 column...I guess it should be DATETIME

Comment: No its varchar and cannot be change

Comment: timediff method is for DATETIME and not for varchar....please provide an example data stored on this column...THen will figure out a solution

Comment: @DevidasMDas Updated the answer. Please mark the answer as ACCEPTED if your problem is solved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97099/discussion-between-devidas-m-das-and-naruto).

Answer (score 1):

You can use  STR_TO_DATE to convert varchar to date, so your query should be:

```
timediff(STR_TO_DATE(date1, '%m/%/d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'), (STR_TO_DATE(date2, '%m/%/d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start_date, end_date)
```

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(), TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2015-12-09 08:00:00', NOW());
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| NOW()               | TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2015-12-09 08:00:00', NOW()) |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-12-09 14:12:51 |                                                 6 |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```